# How to use php to store and read dictionary without json?

Tags: php, json, web, search-engine

I am working on making a search engine, I have to store multiple data against one word, how it will be done using php without use of JSON.
and is it a good approach to do this work in php or I should switch to another Object Oriented Programming Language ?

Comment: how big is your project going to be?

Comment: its kind of research project , at initial level it will have data set of a few 100 words , after doing that I will increase data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its research project, you could give a shot with PHP7 (its faster). PHP5 will also let you achive what you want.
What language you chose is mainly dependand on what you want to achieve. C++ is surely faster than PHP.

Also you would need to check about bigdata handling and non-relational databases (MongoDB for example) which are scalable.

Comment: and what about oracle ?

Comment: no experience with it. But oracle have mainly transactional databases, which will do, but non-transactional and saclable databases are better for those kinds of projects. As you can manipulate structure more easliy.